# produce free *.apk file from android studio 1.1.0

Tags: android

i have developed an app from android studio 1.1.0 and. it work fine with my android studio emulator. now how to generate an *.apk file from the project. it was very easy in eclips. apk was automatically generated.

NOTE: i don't have any signature . i want to develop an free app without anyting to buy. example signature,license and all.

Comment: It's the same with Android Studio, it will generate the apk for you just fine. If you do "run" it will just generate and automatically install the apk using adb with your package name and a debug key. If you want to publish your app without having the phone in debug mode, you do need to sign it with your own signature. Signing won't cost you anything. And it won't cost your users anything either. It isn't really about licensing either. The signature is just a way for people to make sure that any update they download for your app was written by the same developer who wrote your original app.

Comment: so is it posible to install an *.apk file which is generates AUTOMATICALLY bu android studio ? if yes then where it is found ? in which folder.

Comment: where this signature file is found ? from where to download it. ?

Comment: Like nycnik said, Android Studio does everything for you if you just connect your phone to your computer and you turn on usb developer mode on your phone. And yes, it does it "automatically"! Look at lesson 1 of this video course on Android fundamentals on Udacity. https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853 Press the blue button to access the course materials for free (without having to input your credit card number, thought registration will still be required)

Answer (score 0):

Use Grails build.

On the right side of the IDE there is a tab for gradle tasks.  Click that, and then you will see the gradle build options.  You may have to turn out the triangle to see it, but you will see all sorts of options.  Look for "Assemble Release" and double click it.  The status of the build will show in the bottom of the IDE.

[image]

After you run it, your apk can be found in the build directory below the app.

```
app/build/
```

Link for more information:
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: in app/build i have 4 folders. 1->generated 2->intermediat 3->output 4->temp

Comment: in output folder there is apk folder... "AndroidstudioProjects\MyApplication4\app\build\outputs\apk". in that there are 3 files..... 1)app-debud.apk    2)app-debug-unaligned.apk    3)app-debug-unsigned.apk..... which one to send to my mobile phone ?

Comment: app-debud.apk is the one, unaligned is an intermediate product.

Comment: The other link might be the answer you are looking for as well.  You do not need to install the apk manually, just connect the deice, and run the app, it will prompt you for the device to run it on, and you can pick your android device.   The steps above are to deliver someone else the app/apk.